# Mobile site fails to load on ipad from chrome safari

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, ipad

I have some code at the front of my index.php file that calls out to a mobile detect php. It was working fine on iPhone and Android and iPad until one of the more recent ios updates... 8.0 .1 or maybe .2. The code seems to try to forward to the flash page.

It still continues to work on Android and iPhone iOS 7. if possible can someone help me figure out what to change in order to get this script to work with the newer versions of iOS.

```
<?php
$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera    mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
$mobile_browser++;
//Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
$stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
  $tablet_browser++;
}
}

/*if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
   // do something for tablet devices
  // echo 'is tablet';
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something for mobile devices
   echo 'is mobile';
}
else {
   // do something for everything else
  // echo 'is desktop';
}   */

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/

Updates are added on the regular, and popularity ensures momentum going forward with future mobile devices.

Comment: I'm not a code person at all.... i tried to point that out in my original post but they stripped it out... how do i make this work with what i have?? it appears i need it to answer 0?? thats about all i understood from the whole thing... do i point my site to that php or do i download it and add it to my site and periodically check it every once in awhile?? how do i get it to answer 0 for mobile/tablet devices?

Comment: You're going to be a lot better off implementing something that works versus hacky code that can become irrelevant the next day.  Having said that, and understanding you are not a code person, I think https://www.upwork.com would suit you better than stackoverflow.